# On Submit, open windows and perform function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

I am new to JavaScript and i need this function to open in a new popup window when user clicks submit (in case of invalid code).

**What the code should do:**
User enters a code, new windows popups and starts download (if code is right) or takes the user to invalid page (if code is invalid). The invalid page now appears in the parent windows, it needs to be a pop up page and leave the original page behind the popup.

I have already tried target="_blank" in the for bracket, that did not work, I also tried the onSubmit="window.open".

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/R?i=2&Code=" + document.getElementById("url").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
Enter your 6-digit code to start a remote control session:<br> <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> <input type="submit" value="Start Session">
</form>
```

Comment: use `window.open` to open a new window

Comment: Thanks neo for the response and the corrects :). Where should i put the window.open, I tried it in the form bracket and as a replacement to location.href, and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/R?i=2&Code=" + document.getElementById("url").value;
window.open(url);
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
function process() { 
   var url="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/R?i=2&Code=" + document.getElementById("url").value;
   window.open(url);
}
```